# Identifying variations of windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm writing a library that I want to use in programs for a variety of platforms. Here's how I detect the different versions of windows:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)

    #include <winapifamily.h>
    #if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_PC_APP)

        // Windows PC Store App
        #define OS_WINDOWS_STORE

    #endif

    #elif WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)

        // Windows Desktop App
        #define OS_WINDOWS

    #endif

    #elif WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_PHONE_APP)

        // Windows Phone App
        #define OS_WINDOWS_PHONE

    #endif

    #elif WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)

        // Windows RT Store App
        #define OS_WINDOWS_RT

    #endif

#elif defined(_WIN32_) || defined(_WIN32)

    // Windows Desktop App
    #define OS_WINDOWS

#endif
```

My understanding is WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION should be set to DESKTOP for any x86 programs, PC_APP for windows store apps on x86, so I check for PC_APP before DESKTOP. Then, PHONE_APP for Windows 8 Phone apps, and APP is defined for everything, so I assume if none of the other ones succeeded we must be going for a WinRT app. Is this correct? Also, I believe this header is only included in recent versions of MSVC, what is the cutoff point I should use before defaulting to the Win32 check? Is anything before 2011 good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the reason you want to distinguish between these, there are better ways to approach this problem than your approach. E.g. if you want to know what API you can access, you should just use the recommended approach and check the `WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION` at the appropriate point in your code.

If you want to use your approach, there are a number of problems. First, you've got mismatched #ifdefs. Second, `WINAPI_PARTITION_APP` is a deprecated constant and is the same as `WINAPI_FAMILY_PC_APP`. Third if you really want to identify Windows RT build, you need to check CPU, not `WINAPI_FAMILY`, since Windows RT (i.e. Windows 8.1 on ARM) and Windows 8.1 Store (i.e. Windows Store apps on x86 or x86-64) both have the same API available to them.

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)

    #include <winapifamily.h>
    #if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_PC_APP)

        #if _M_ARM

            // Windows RT Store App
            #define OS_WINDOWS_RT

        #else

            // Windows PC Store App
            #define OS_WINDOWS_STORE

        #endif

    #elif WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)

        // Windows Desktop App
        #define OS_WINDOWS

    #elif WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_PHONE_APP)

        // Windows Phone App
        #define OS_WINDOWS_PHONE

    #endif

#elif defined(_WIN32_) || defined(_WIN32)

    // Windows Desktop App
    #define OS_WINDOWS

#endif
```